# Uniquness of stress tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

[image]
I am struggling to understand how to derive a stress tensor. In the picture above, I was asked to compute the stress tensor and the stress acting on the plane $\Sigma$. The x-axis and y-axis are in the horizontal and the vertical direction, while the z-axis is through the monitor.

First, I drew a vertical line going through the center of the plane $\Sigma$ and considered the force balance of the right half of the rectangle given by the vertical line (as in the picture). Because the half of the rectangle does not move, the force acting on the left side must be $f$ in the negative x direction. So, I thought the first column of the stress tensor must be $[-f, 0, 0]^T$, which was not correct. The answer was $[f, 0, 0]$. If I were to consider the force balance of the left half of the rectangle, I can get the answer by the same argument. So, the stress tensor is not unique? What is wrong with my argument?

Comment: The stress vector acting on the plane $\Sigma$ is not f,0,0.  Remove the right trapezoidal wedge, and replace it with a force acting on the plane $\Sigma$.  What are the components of that force perpendicular and parallel to $\Sigma$.  The perpendicular force component translates into a normal stress, and the parallel component translates into a shear stress.  This is a simplified derivation of the so-called Cauchy Stress Relationship.

Comment: Thank you! I will check into Cauchy Stress Relationship.